# CSS does not work sometime in android webview

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I'm writting a webview opening my local html.I'm using [this HTML5WebView](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/trunk/HTML5WebView/src/org/itri/html5webview/HTML5WebView.java). But it is not strong enough for me. CSS in html works well, but CSS in ".css" file cannot work very well. 
For example, the attribute "height" in ".css" file cannot be implemented in html. So I have to set "height" attribute in html again to make it work. Like this:

## my css file:

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;    
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
}
.header_title{
    position:fixed;
    *position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    top:0px; 
    opacity=1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
.header_title_btn{
    width:50%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    opacity=1; 
    text-align:center;
}
.lineMiddle{
    height:80px; 
    line-height:80px;
}
```

## my html file:

[image]

I want to know if there are some methods to solve this problem, because I have lots of html and CSS files.